# Individual origin VS Median point

Tags: faces, scale, origin

I'm following this tutorial https://youtu.be/-0tMeMZpeXE?t=147. At 2.27 he extrudes those faces but with an unusual angle. He changes to "Individual origin" and it works fine.

When I try it it doesn't work as expected (see attached image where I've changed to Individual origin but with no luck). It only works if I Shift+Z during scaling.

[image: Scaling with Individual origin. The two faces touch themselves]

Comment: oh ok you're right, extrude along normals won't work for this topology, sorry   ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he has made a small mistake. Neither of these two settings will give the desired result, on the left *Median Point* (will place the center of the scale at the center of all the selections), on the right *Individual Origins* (each selection will have its own center of scale):

[image]

Actually as you can see when he scales, he constrains the scale on the Z axis (X axis and Y axis are visible, not Z axis), that's why it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Hadn't noticed that he still scales while constraining the Z axis (still a newbie).

Your second suggestion though (Extrude Along Normals) doesn't produce the same result.

[image]

Comment: you're right I didn't use the same topology, but please don't use the "Your Answer" field to comment, use the "add a comment" button  ;)

Comment: I know, but I couldn't find a way to post a picture as well. Commenting doesn't allow that. Is there a workaround?

Comment: You should be able to edit your first question and add whatever you want